# Common Lisp: how to pass keyword arguments to another function?

Tags: parameter-passing, common-lisp

Common Lisp newbie here. I am having trouble understanding parameter passing in Lisp functions. For example, imagine the following function definition in Common Lisp (say, SBCL):

```
(defun foo (x <&-keyword goes here> args)
  (let ((v (make-hash-table args)))
    (setf (gethash "foo" v) x)
    v))
```

My question is: is there a *&-keyword* I could specify to pass keyword arguments in `foo` to `make-hash-table` in this situation? I already tried `&rest` as a &-keyword, and it always gives me the following warning:

```
; caught WARNING:
;   The function MAKE-HASH-TABLE is called with odd number of keyword arguments.
```

I also read about `&allow-other-keys` as a possible &-keyword, yet don't seem to find how can the other keys be used by `make-hash-table` within `foo`. Thus, I'm stumped. Can keyword parameters be passed to internal function calls in Common Lisp? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`apply`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm):

```
(defun foo (x &rest mht-arguments)
  (let ((v (apply #'make-hash-table mht-arguments)))
    (setf (gethash "foo" v) x)
    v))
```

See also [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56742980/850781) on how to combine that with `&key`.

Comment: Thank you. This works, though it is a bit unnerving to me how every argument just gets swallowed up by &rest. I come from domain-specific R where the language just automagically determines which parameters are passed on to which function. But this is better I guess, since you *have* to know what is being passed on. Thanks again.

Comment: You can do that too - you can make `foo` accept a _single_ list argument containing all the `make-hash-table` args.